# Sending email: Connection reset by peer

Tags: c++, sockets, email, smtp

Lets say I have a function like below that sends and receives info from a socket flawlessly..

The results are:

```
Connected to: 65.55.96.11 Port: 25
220 BLU0-SMTP374.blu0.hotmail.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.4675 ready at  Mon, 31 Dec 2012 19:52:22 -0800 

250 BLU0-SMTP374.blu0.hotmail.com Hello [50.100.44.155]

220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

Exception: Socket Error 10054: Connection reset by peer
```

Why do I get an exception? It throws the exception when I send the "DATA" string.

How do I login? I cannot seem to find out how anywhere online. I searched it and only see AUTH command but no usage or examples at all.

The code is below:

```
void SendEmail(std::string Username, std::string Password, std::string IP, std::string Port)
{
  Socket = CreateSocket;
  ConnectSocket(Socket, IP, Port);
  SetTimeout(Socket, 10000);
  SocketInfo(Socket, IP, Port);

  writeln("Connected to: " + IP + " Port: " + Port);
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "HELO");    //SendSocketEx automatically adds \r\n to the end of a line..
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "STARTTLS");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "MAIL FROM: mehwtfbleh@hotmail.com");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "VRFY mehwtfbleh@hotmail.com");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "RCPT TO: mehwtfbleh@hotmail.com");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "DATA");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "This Is The Body..");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  SendSocketEx(Socket, "QUIT");
  writeln(RecvSocket(Socket));

  CloseSocket(Socket);
  FreeSocket(Socket);
}

int main()
{
    SendEmail("", "", "smtp.live.com", "25", "localhost");
}
```

Comment: "I have a function like below that sends and receives info from a socket flawlessly.." - erm , how can it be flawless if it throws an exception?

Comment: Because it sends and receives the data just fine. I just cannot figure out how to login.. It throws an exception because something cannot be send. I think it's authentication is the reason? It sent the first couple commands and received the responses just fine :l

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that this server requires communication to occur over the TLS protocol. The [STARTTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS) command tells the server that all further communication will occur over the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL/TLS). Once this connection is established, all further communication between the 2 sides is encrypted.

The easiest way to accomplish that is to use a [library that implements SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations). The most famous library is OpenSSL.

You can perform a quick test using OpenSSL from your terminal/console:

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.live.com:25 -starttls smtp -crlf
```

Then you can send your commands:

```
EHLO hotmail.com
AUTH LOGIN (this depends on the methods supported by the server)
...
MAIL FROM: <your email>
RCPT TO: <recipient email>
DATA
All your SMTP are belong to us.
.
```